# Overwrite a previously sent event in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, html5-audio

I am trying to track how long a live audio stream is being played in Google Analytics.

My code listens for a current time change in the HTML audio tag and sends an event when the time is a multiple of 0.5 minutes (30 seconds):

```
var audio = document.getElementById('livestream');//The Audio element
var prevTime = -1;

audio.addEventListener('timeupdate',function(){

    playTime = (Math.floor(audio.currentTime)/60);

    setTimeout(function() { 

        if (playTime % 0.5 === 0 && prevTime !== playTime && playTime !== 0){

            prevTime = playTime;
            ga('send', 'event', 'Stream', playTime);

        }

    }, 500);

},false);
```

This works well, however if one user listens for 1 minute and another for 2 minutes I end up with skewed results because there are now six entries:

```
Action    Label    Sessions
Stream    0.5      2
Stream    1.0      2
Stream    1.5      1
Stream    2.0      1
```

What I want to do is overwrite a previously sent event so that I am left with:

```
Action    Label    Sessions
Stream    1.0      1
Stream    2.0      1
```

The data I want to get from this is average listening time and total listening time.

Also should I use an event Label or Value for this? I have only seen other examples where the Label is used but surely value is better?

I may very well be going about this the wrong way so any advice would be very useful to me!

Comment: If you want total time the best way would probably be to create a custom metric (metric are added up) and then look at this in a custom report (custom metrics do not show up in standard reports).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want to do is overwrite a previously sent event so that I am left with:

Once data is inserted into Google analytics it can not be changed.  The data is read only.

> Also should I use an event Label or Value for this?

Thats up to you.  But if you dont intend of doing some kind of total or some of thees minutes then there wont be any need to have them as a value.

Comment: Thanks for that, so is there a way to ignore previous entries in the Google Analytics dashboard?

Comment: Add a filter to the view but with data like that it's going to be hard to only remove those rows